# What is the connection between Google cloud platform and Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to have media data somewhere on the Cloud and download them by my Android app. I found out that this should be done by the Google Cloud Platform.

But when I started to investigate I learned that I need to have Firebase Storage first. But do I still need the Cloud Platform then? Isn't it the same thing?

To be honest I don't understand the difference between these two.

So what is the difference and connection between the Google Cloud Platform and Firebase Storage? And how do they cooperate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com) is a group of over 100 cloud based products offered by Google. Instead of covering that, I'm going to assume you are asking about Google [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), which is one of those 100+ products, and which deals with storing and retrieving files.

Cloud Storage has a set of [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) that you can call from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or a serverless environment like Cloud Functions. It does **not** offer SDKs for direct access from client-side platforms such as Android.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) is also part of Google, and is a so-called serverless platform: it offers SDKs that can be used directly within your client-side application code. In this specific scenario, Firebase offers [SDKs that access Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage) from Android, iOS and Web clients.

To allow you to secure access to the files in Cloud Storage, Firebase relies on [authenticating the user](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth), and then a set of [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) that you configure and that define [who can access what files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#cloud-storage_2).

This combination of accessing Cloud Storage through Firebase is officially called Cloud Storage for Firebase, but often still referred to by its previous name of Firebase Storage.